# Angular dropbox api /token endpoint returns invalid request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk-js

I'm trying to build a connection to dropbo using angular.js. For this i have the following piece of code to do a request to https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/oauth2/token .

The code is obtained in the url after the user clicks-through to the verification url of dropbox and back. $scope.accessUrl = 'https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?client_id=szj63bffo9rp5v7&response_type=' + $scope.response_type + '&redirect_uri=' + $scope.redirect_uri;
This seems to work, since a code is returned via get and it is available in function below.

```
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                code: <<<<token>>>>,
                client_id: '<<<<mydropbox.key>>>>',
                client_secret: '<<<<mydropbox.secret>>>>',
                redirect_uri: "http://localhost:8080",

                contentType: "application/json",
                url: "https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/oauth2/token"
            })
```

However, I've tried for a while to get this working and it I'm stuck. I'm not sure what is causing this error but it is always the following response:
error:"invalid_request"
error_description:"No auth function available for given request"

And the HTTP status code is always 400 (bad request).

I'm new to angular. A similar $http request has worked for a different endpoint. For this endpoint I put Bearer: <<<< authorization key that should be returned from broken function above >>>> in the url and a path in data{} of the body.

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong, of which I'm guessing it's likely a silly mistake, I'd love some help.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass required data in `data` property as dictionary.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage

If you need to pass some data in headers, use `headers` property.
[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage)

```
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            data: {
                 grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                 code: <<<<token>>>>,
                 client_id: '<<<<mydropbox.key>>>>',
                 client_secret: '<<<<mydropbox.secret>>>>',
                 redirect_uri: "http://localhost:8080"
            },
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/oauth2/token"
        })
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense. However, the response from the dropbox API is still the same after changing this.{"error_description": "No auth function available for given request", "error": "invalid_request"}

Comment: I think you need to use 'GET' request instead of 'POST' one. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. The API documentation of dropbox didn't notice me of the fact I had to send contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

They noticed that in general you should send json so I assumed this was true unless mentioned otherwise.